# Installation of Kubernetes-node fails with conflicting packages on CentOs 7

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When i am trying to install kubernetes-node with the following command
it fails with an error

```
[abkari@condor network-scripts]$ sudo yum install docker kubernetes-node

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

    base: centos.skarta.net
    epel: epel.besthosting.ua
    extras: ftp.crc.dk
    updates: centos.uib.no Resolving Dependencies --> Running transaction check ---> Package docker.x86_64 0:1.8.2-10.el7.centos will be installed --> Processing Dependency: docker-selinux >= 1.8.2-10.el7.centos for package: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64 ---> Package kubernetes-node.x86_64 0:1.2.0-0.6.alpha1.git8632732.el7 will be installed --> Processing Dependency: socat for package: kubernetes-node-1.2.0-0.6.alpha1.git8632732.el7.x86_64 --> Running transaction check ---> Package docker-selinux.x86_64 0:1.8.2-10.el7.centos will be installed ---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.2.2-5.el7 will be installed --> Processing Conflict: docker-engine-selinux-1.10.3-1.el7.centos.noarch conflicts docker-selinux --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have uninstalled/removed the docker still the error exists !

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing docker packages. Package `docker` is Redhat's Docker. Package `docker-engine` is Docker's Docker. *kubernetes-node* has Docker's docker dependency + you are asking to install also Redhat's Docker => conflict. Try:

```
sudo yum install docker-engine kubernetes-node
```

Comment: --> Processing Conflict: docker-engine-selinux-1.10.3-1.el7.centos.noarch conflicts docker-selinux
--> Processing Conflict: docker-engine-1.10.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts docker-io
--> Processing Conflict: docker-engine-1.10.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts docker
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Still the same problem

Comment: "docker-io"? That's old name of docker-engine. You are mixing docker versions now :-). Be sure that you are using only current docker repository - delete old Docker repos definitions.

Comment: You are right docker-io is the old one. I have deleted all the versions of the docker engines and executed the above command. Still facing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you already have docker installed, I assume the most recent version from the docker repo. That command is trying to install it again from a different repo. Try running this instead:

`sudo yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni`

It will install the required kubernetes tools without docker.